# Does Lymph Clot?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, circulatory-system, lymphatic-system

According to my professor, lymph has the ability to clot because it contains plasma which has dissolved fibrinogen. He says that as long fibrinogen is present in a bodily fluid, it should be able to clot.

I always thought lymph would not be able to clot as it lacks the thrombocytes to initiate the coagulation pathway. Without thrombocytes the Stuart–Prower Factor would never be released into the lymph stream, and hence the coagulation cascade never occurs.

So does lymph have the ability to clot, and what would be the mechanism for the clotting of lymph?

Comment: There happens to be a relatively recent (2021) [review](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34901222/) on just this subject, also known as lymphatic thrombosis. The text is open access. Unfortunately I don't have time to write a full answer now (hence the comment), but if you're having trouble understanding the paper let me know and I'll write an answer covering the areas you have questions about.